# AngularJS ng-view clears out on before new content is load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-view, route-provider, location-provider

I'm new to AngularJS and made an app which changes page without reloading it.
But as I'm requesting the page I'm checking if request was made with ajax or not, if so I'm returning only needed part for angular, if else I give browser an entire page with layout. It means, that if visitor enters to page by entering address to browsers address bar he should see that page without angular loading it.

**So my problem is:** When I open page by entering address it shows content, that I need, but then - angular catches route `.when('/some/page')` and loads it, and as it does it, it clears all content in ng-view (for half of second or less) and then shows same content, but loaded by angular. This short content "blinking" and unneeded request irritates me, and I don't even know what I should be searching for.

Is it possible to prevent angular from loading the page if visitor is already in it? Or to change that content clearing behaviour (but I have an idea that it takes this much time to add new content to DOM).

Comment: can you share the code with jsfiddle or plnkr?

Comment: Do you mean something like `ng-cloak`? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: Doesn't make sense trying to serve the same route from server. Should be loading the same index page each time and let angular manage the view.

Comment: @Sumant i will try to make an example later, now code is in pretty project.

Comment: @Icepickle will check it, still not sure what it does by reading docs.

Comment: @charlietfl Yeah, i know that, just thought that it can lose one unessasary http request, do some improvement for older crawlers or event some support for older IE.

Comment: defintiely need rendered content for seo but that's usually done through `?_escaped_fragment_` in url

Comment: @charlietfl well i'am using php framework for its a lot easer to do ajax check than use `?_escaped_fragment_` to include pages.